# How do I search within a particular directory using the locate command?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Sorry, this question is going to be total newb factor.  How do I search within a particular directory using the locate command?

The following command isn't working for me:

```
# locate -i mnt/external/Songs/"tangerine"
```

I would like to search within the "Songs" folder.

Comment: Besides the answer @enzotib gave you can also `grep` the output from `locate`: `locate tangerine | grep mnt/external/Songs *` if you want to look for `tangerine` that `includes mnt/external/Songs`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want

```
locate -ir 'mnt/external/Songs/.*tangerine'
```

`-r` is for regular expressions search, like in `grep`. You may also use plain globs for situations as simple as this:

```
locate /mnt/external/Songs/*tangerine*
```

Comment: Thank you enzo.  I prefer the second line of code you provided because I can autocomplete with tab

Answer (score 1):

Give the find command a try

`find /mnt/external/Songs/ -iname tangerine*`

***Example:*** I wanted to search for songs with the word  *concerto* in their filename in my *Music* folder, so :

```
  nits@nits-workstation:~$ find /mnt/Storage_1/Music/ -iname *concerto*
```

Output:

```
/mnt/Storage_1/Music/Music I/Antonio Vivaldi - The Four Seasons and Violin Concertos
/mnt/Storage_1/Music/Music I/Antonio Vivaldi - The Four Seasons and Violin Concertos/10. Concerto No. 4 In F Minor, Rv 297 'winter' - I Allegro Non Molto.mp3
/mnt/Storage_1/Music/Music I/Antonio Vivaldi - The Four Seasons and Violin Concertos/01. Concerto No. 1 In E, Rv 269 'spring' - I Allegro.mp3
```

[This](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_findx.htm) is a nice tutorial for the `find` command.

Comment: Is there any way we can do this with locate?  Find is super slow on my external =(

Comment: This article is good too! https://help.ubuntu.com/community/find

Comment: @LedZeppelin: Agreed , community documentation is the best. For the locate command look at entozib's answer below.